# Using file1 as an Index to search file2 when file1 contains extra informations

Tags: linux, bash, awk

as you can read in the title Im dealing with two files. Her is the example how the look like.

file1:

Name (additional info separated by a tab from the name)

```
Peter Schwarzer<tab>Best friend of mine
```

file2:

Name (followed by a float separated by a tab from the name)

```
Peter Schwarzer<tab>1456
```

So what i want to do is use file1 one as an index for searching file2. If the Names match it should be written in file3 which should contain the Name followed by the float from file2 followed by the additional info from file1.
So file3 should look like:

```
Peter Schwarzer<tab>1456<tab>Best friend of mine
```

(everything separated by tab)

I tried grep -f to read a pattern from a file and without the additional information it works. So is there any way to get the desired result with grep or is AWK the answer?

Thanks in advance, 
Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this line a try, I didn't test, but should go:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR{n[$1]=$2;next}$1 in n{print $0,n[$1]}' file1 file2 > file3
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats what I was searching for :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk one liner!

```
awk -v FS="\t" -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==NR{ A[$1]=$2; next}$1 in A{print $0,A[$1];}' file1.txt  file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Comment: @JFS31 I have to be faster answering!!

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a job for `join`:

```
join -t '\t' file1 file2
```

This assumes `file1` and `file2` are sorted.  If not, sort them first:

```
sort -o file1 file1
sort -o file2 file2
join -t '\t' file1 file2
```

If you can't modify `file1` and `file2` (if you need to leave them in their original, unsorted state), use a temporary file:

```
tmpfile=/tmp/tf$$
sort file1 > $tmpfile
sort file2 | join -t '\t' $tmpfile -
```

If `join` says "illegal tab character specification" you'll have to use `join -t ' '` where you type an actual tab between the single quotes (and depending on your shell, you may have to use control-V before that tab).

Comment: Thank you for this additional idea. Never tried join before :)